# SQL Server Query Help required

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-3

I've written a query which retrieves top 5 records from a table like this

```
SELECT Top(5)  Activity, GETUTCDATE() as CurrentDate
    FROM Activities
    WHERE UserID = @uid
    ORDER BY ActivityDate DESC
```

and on View i am displaying top 5 records and i also have a link of More on clicking of which next 5 records should show,again clicking on that link show next 5 records and so on

I am having confusion on how to write this query ie how to get next 5 records then next 5 and so on

Comment: maybe you can add row_count and retrieve the data based on row_count...

Comment: pretty sure GETUTCDATE is a MSSQL fn only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the RowNumber function and a CTE to achieve paging in your example this would be something like.

```
With UserActivityData as  (
SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ActivityDate DESC) as RowNum,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ActivityDate ASC) as InverseRowNum 
    FROM Activities
    WHERE UserID = @uid
    ) 

SELECT * from UserActivityData where RowNum between @StartIndex and @StartIndex + 4
```